# Create optimized docker image with multi layer jar file using Gradle

Tags: java, docker, gradle, jar

I'm trying to build an efficient Docker image that leverages Docker’s image layering to decrease the duration and the required bandwidth for uploading to or downloading from the repository. Is there any way to separate my compiled code and dependencies (external libs) using `Gradle` build tools?

My current `Dockerfile` copies the `fat jar` to the container, while the most significant part of the jar file is libraries that don’t change between releases.

My current Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim

VOLUME /tmp

WORKDIR /app

# Add the application's jar to the container
COPY /build/libs/app-*.jar app.jar

# Run the jar file
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","app.jar"]
```

Edit 1: I'm trying to achieve this goal without using any plugin (if it's possible).

Answer (score 1):

Well, maybe a tool like https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib is more what you are looking for? It has been made precisely for this kind of use case.

With "pure" Docker, the whole build is done in your Dockerfile, with at the beginning a command to dowload the dependencies, and **THEN** adding your code to the image with a copy. This way, the first layers can be cached. You should probably start from an official Gradle image then. And since your dependencies will be included, you can even get away with running your software by directly calling Gradle. The image size will be bigger, but only your code would be sent over the network each time, unless your dependencies change.

There are a lot of other options to achieve something similar with Docker, but many of them break the reproducibility of the build, by using local caches, or downloading the dependencies directly from the target machine. They work, but then you lose the "universal container" approach of Docker.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The library seems interesting to me, and I will check it. But I was seeking a solution that doesn't need any plugin. TBH, plugins that create Docker images make the project unclear or unreadable since you have to search a lot to find out how a project is being built.